# calculate holidays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created the following JavaScript to calculate holidays that are not fixed.  It works it seems.  My questions, though, are can it be written more efficiently and did I omit anything that would improve it?

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();

//  lowercase is used
var first = 1,second = 2,third = 3,fourth = 4;  // Which occurrence in a given month.  If there ma be a fifth occurrence, use "last."
var last = 99;  //  Find last occurrence of weekday in a month.  "last" set to "99".

//  lowercase used for weekday names
var sun = 0,mon = 1,tue = 2,wed = 3,thu = 4,fri = 5,sat = 6;  // JavaScript nubers weekdays 0 - 6 for Sundayear through Saturdayear.
var sunday = 0,monday = 1,tuesday = 2,wednesday = 3,thursday = 4,friday = 5,saturday = 6;

//  lowercase used for month names
var jan = 0,feb = 1,mar =2 ,apr = 3 ,may = 4,jun = 5,jul = 6,aug = 7,sep = 8,oct = 9,nov=10,dec = 11;  //  JavaScript numbers months 0 - 11, not 1 - 12.
var january = 0,february = 1,march = 2,april = 3,may = 4,june = 5,july = 6,august = 7,september = 8,october = 9,november = 10,december = 11;


function findHoliday(occurrence,weekday,month,year) {  // Find the 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', or 'last' weekday occurrence in a given month and year.

  /*  Note: Numbers may be used instead of text.

      occurrence = first; second; third; fourth; or last
      weekday = sun; mon; tue; wed; thu; fri; or sat  
      month = jan; feb; mar; apr; mayear; jun; jul; aug; sep; oct; nov; or dec
      year = year from the variable 'year', or a specific year may be used such as 1990, 2010, 2017, etc.

      Syntax Examples:  findHoliday(third,mon,jan,year)     Martin Luther King, Jr. Dayear is US.
                        findHoliday(last,mon,mayear,2017)   Memorial Day in US.
  */


  /*  The most efficient method to find the 'last' (or 5th, if it exists) occurrence of a Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, or Sat in a month is to find its first
      occurrence in the following month and then subtract 7 days from that date.  That is what the following 'if' statement does.
  */


  if (occurrence === 99) {
      var theDate = new Date(year,month+1,1+((first - (weekday >= new Date(year,month+1,1).getDay())) * 7) + (weekday - new Date(year,month+1,1).getDay())-7);
  }

  //  Finds the 'first', 'second', 'third', or 'fourth' occurrence of a weekday in a month.
  if (occurrence !== 99) {
      var theDate = new Date(year,month,1+((occurrence - (weekday >= new Date(year,month,1).getDay())) * 7) + (weekday - new Date(year,month,1).getDay()));
  }

      /* EDIT below to end of function to adapt to your needs */

    var holiday = "";

  if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 1 && month == 0) { holiday = "Martin Luther King, Jr. Dayear"; }
  if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 1 && month == 1) { holiday = "President's Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 2) { holiday = "Daylight Savings Time Begins"; }
  if (occurrence == 4 && weekday == 3 && month == 3) { holiday = "Administrative Assistants Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 4) { holiday = "Mother's Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 99 && weekday == 1 && month == 4) { holiday = "Memorial Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 0 && month == 5) { holiday = "Father's Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 0 && month == 6) { holiday = "Parents Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 1 && weekday == 1 && month == 8) { holiday = "Labor Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 8) { holiday = "Grandparents Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 99 && weekday == 0 && month == 8) { holiday = "Gold Star Mothers Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 1 && month == 9) { holiday = "Columbus Day"; }
  if (occurrence == 1 && weekday == 0 && month == 10) { holiday = "Daylight Savings Time Ends"; }
  if (occurrence == 4 && weekday == 4 && month == 10) { holiday = "Thanksgiving Day"; }


  var weekday = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  var mMonth = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

  var displayDate = "";

  if (holiday == ""){
     var displayDate = weekday[theDate.getDay()] + ', ' + mMonth[theDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + theDate.getDate() + ', ' + year;
  }

  if (holiday != "") {
      var displayDate = weekday[theDate.getDay()] + ', ' + mMonth[theDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + theDate.getDate() + ', ' + year + ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + holiday;
  }   

    return displayDate;

}  //  End of 'findHoliday(o,d,m,year)' function


 // Examples Only:  Delete as is not part of this script.
 document.write(findHoliday(third,sunday,june,year) + '<p>')
   document.write(findHoliday(3,0,5,2015));
 // End of Examples
```

Comment: You can use if-else statements rather than a large chain of if. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Also, to construct the date string, you could have used javascript's Date object which would have simply taken the day month and year as parameters to its constructor.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of that block of `if` statements, you should have a dictionary of holidays accessible with a key.  Your function should just construct a key from the input and see if a holiday exists with that key.

I would break out the functionality to find holidays and find dates into separate functions.  You can then have a third function that returns a string representation of the date, including the holiday if any.

Do every thing zero based.  If you want the first occurrence of a day in the month, pass `0`.  To count from the end of the month, pass negative numbers indicating how many weeks to count back.  So, for the last occurrence of a day in the month, pass `-1`.  These changes make it easy to find a date using math.

The built-in `Date.toLocaleDateString()` already produces the date string you are looking for. You might consider using that instead.  Either way, don't repeat the code that constructs the date string.  Create the date string, then if there is a holiday, append it to the date string.

```js
const holidays = { // keys are formatted as month,week,day
    "0,2,1": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
    "1,2,1": "President's Day",
    "2,1,0": "Daylight Savings Time Begins",
    "3,3,3": "Administrative Assistants Day",
    "4,1,0": "Mother's Day",
    "4,-1,1": "Memorial Day",
    "5,2,0": "Father's Day",
    "6,2,0": "Parents Day",
    "8,0,1": "Labor Day",
    "8,1,0": "Grandparents Day",
    "8,-1,0": "Gold Star Mothers Day",
    "9,1,1": "Columbus Day",
    "10,0,0": "Daylight Savings Time Ends",
    "10,3,4": "Thanksgiving Day"
};
function getDate(year, month, week, day) {
    const firstDay = 1;
    if (week < 0) {
        month++;
    }
    const date = new Date(year, month, (week * 7) + firstDay);
    if (day < date.getDay()) {
        day += 7;
    }
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() + day);
    return date;
}
function getHoliday(month, week, day) {
    return holidays[month + "," + week + "," + day];
}
function getDateString(year, month, week, day) {
    const date = getDate(year, month, week, day);
    const holiday = getHoliday(month, week, day);
    let dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
    if (holiday) {
        dateString += " \xa0\xa0\xa0" + holiday;
    }
    return dateString;
}
console.log(getDateString(2021, 4, -1, 1)); // Memorial Day, 2021
```

Comment: Thanks, gilly3!  There are more functions, but also more options with them.

Comment: This is off by about a week for most of these dates this year (2019). Also, President's Day is on the 3rd Monday, not the 2nd.

Comment: @derekantrican - thank you, I have fixed the bug and updated my answer.  The code was failing any time the day was earlier in the week than the day for the first of the month.

Comment: This didn't work for Memorial Day 2021 when the very last day of the month was a Monday

Comment: @Cassova - thanks for letting me know.  I fixed the code in my answer by removing the `firstDay--` line.  That line should have been removed when I fixed the last bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with @gilly3 's answer trying to use it with the current year (2019). Most of the holiday dates generated were off by about a week. So I adapted an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470102/2246411) that works for me

*Important thing to note about this version: instead of using "-1" for the last holiday of the month, it uses "5". And "week" is not longer zero-based (like gilly3's answer) but is "1-based" (like OP's original code)*

```
var holidays = { // keys are formatted as month,week,day
    "0,3,1": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",      //3rd Mon in Jan
    "1,3,1": "President's Day",                  //3rd Mon in Feb
    "2,2,0": "Daylight Savings Time Begins",     //2nd Sun in Mar
    "3,3,3": "Administrative Professionals Day", //3rd Wed in Apr
    "4,2,0": "Mother's Day",                     //2nd Sun in May (in the US, but not all countries)
    "4,5,1": "Memorial Day",                     //Last Mon in May
    "5,3,0": "Father's Day",                     //3rd Sun in Jun (in the US, but not all countries)
    "6,4,0": "Parents Day",                      //4th Sun of Jul
    "8,1,1": "Labor Day",                        //1st Mon in Sept
    //"8,1,0": "Grandparents Day",               //Technically this is the 1st Sun AFTER Labor Day
                                                 //  so can't be represented perfectly this way
    "8,5,0": "Gold Star Mothers Day",            //Last Sun in Sep
    "9,2,1": "Columbus Day",                     //2nd Mon in Oct
    "10,1,0": "Daylight Savings Time Ends",      //1st Sun in Nov
    "10,4,4": "Thanksgiving Day"                 //4th Thurs in Nov
};

function getDate(year, month, week, day) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, 1),
      add = (day - date.getDay() + 7) % 7 + (week - 1) * 7;

  // make sure that we stay in the same month
  do {
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setDate(1 + add);
    add -= 7;
  } while (date.getMonth() != month);

  return date;
}

function getHoliday(month, week, day) {
    return holidays[month + "," + week + "," + day];
}

function getDateString(year, month, week, day) {
    var date = getDate(year, month, week, day);
    var holiday = getHoliday(month, week, day);
    var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
    if (holiday) {
        dateString += " \xa0\xa0\xa0" + holiday;
    }
    return dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have the need to count the holidays but only care to know whether a given day is a holiday then you can use the following plain javascript function that doesnt use any libraries.

This function returns name of the holiday if input date is holiday otherwise returns empty string.

This solution satisfies following requirements that I had:

- No Frameworks
- Ability to define fix date holidays (e.g. 1st Jan is
  holiday) in human readable format (avoiding zero based scales)
- Ability to define relative holidays (e.g. 1st Monday of September is
  holiday) in as human readable format as possible.
- If possible make
  single javascript function with say only 50 lines of code

.

```
function isBankHoliday(date) {
    // static holidays
    const isDate = (d, month, date) => {
        return d.getMonth() == (month - 1) && d.getDate() == date;
    };
    if (isDate(date, 1, 1)) { return "New Year"; }
    else if (isDate(date, 7, 4)) { return "Independence Day"; }
    else if (isDate(date, 11, 11)) { return "Veterans Day"; }
    else if (isDate(date, 12, 25)) { return "Christmas Day"; }

    // dynamic holidays
    const isDay = (d, month, day, occurance) => {
        if (d.getMonth() == (month - 1) && d.getDay() == day) {
            if (occurance > 0) {
                return occurance == Math.ceil(d.getDate() / 7);
            } else {
                // check last occurance
                let _d = new Date(d);
                _d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
                return _d.getMonth() > d.getMonth();
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    if (isDay(date, 1, 1, 3)) { return "MLK Day"; }
    else if (isDay(date, 2, 1, 3)) { return "Presidents Day"; }
    else if (isDay(date, 5, 1, -1)) { return "Memorial Day"; }
    else if (isDay(date, 9, 1, 1)) { return "Labor Day"; }
    else if (isDay(date, 10, 1, 2)) { return "Columbus Day"; }
    else if (isDay(date, 11, 4, 4)) { return "Thanksgiving Day"; }

    // Non Business days
    if (date.getDay() == 0) { return "Sunday"; }
    else if (date.getDay() == 6) { return "Saturday" }

    // not a holiday
    return "";
}
```

Tests:

```js
function isBankHoliday(date) {
    
        // static holidays
        const isDate = (d, month, date) => {
            return d.getMonth() == (month - 1) && d.getDate() == date;
        };
        if (isDate(date, 1, 1)) { return "New Year"; }
        else if (isDate(date, 7, 4)) { return "Independence Day"; }
        else if (isDate(date, 11, 11)) { return "Veterans Day"; }
        else if (isDate(date, 12, 25)) { return "Christmas Day"; }
    
        // dynamic holidays
        const isDay = (d, month, day, occurance) => {
            if (d.getMonth() == (month - 1) && d.getDay() == day) {
                if (occurance > 0) {
                    return occurance == Math.ceil(d.getDate() / 7);
                } else {
                    // check last occurance
                    let _d = new Date(d);
                    _d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
                    return _d.getMonth() > d.getMonth();
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        if (isDay(date, 1, 1, 3)) { return "MLK Day"; }
        else if (isDay(date, 2, 1, 3)) { return "Presidents Day"; }
        else if (isDay(date, 5, 1, -1)) { return "Memorial Day"; }
        else if (isDay(date, 9, 1, 1)) { return "Labor Day"; }
        else if (isDay(date, 10, 1, 2)) { return "Columbus Day"; }
        else if (isDay(date, 11, 4, 4)) { return "Thanksgiving Day"; }
    
        // Non Business days
        if (date.getDay() == 0) { return "Sunday"; }
        else if (date.getDay() == 6) { return "Saturday" }
    
        // not a holiday
        return "";
    }
    
    
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 00, 01)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 06, 04)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 10, 11)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 11, 25)));

    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 00, 20)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 01, 17)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 04, 25)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 08, 07)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 09, 12)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 10, 26)));

    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 00, 16)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 01, 20)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 04, 29)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 08, 04)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 09, 09)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 10, 23)));

    // Weekends
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 4)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 12)));

    // Negatives
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 00, 02)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 04, 18)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 04, 26)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 04, 22)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 04, 30)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2017, 04, 31)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 6)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 8)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 10)));
    console.log(isBankHoliday(new Date(2020, 0, 31)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post when I was looking for a way to detect floating holidays.  My original intent was to hide some elements on the page during federal holidays and on custom dates. Here are some improvements based on best-refactoring practices. I won't be addressing holidays that are on a fixed date like New Years or Christmas.

Creating these helpers may seem like a bit too much, but they make things so much more readable and easy to follow.  I've only included Federal holidays.

```js
var SUN = 1,
  MON = 2,
  TUE = 3,
  WED = 4,
  THU = 5,
  FRI = 6,
  SAT = 7;

var JAN = 1,
  FEB = 2,
  MAR = 3,
  APR = 4,
  MAY = 5,
  JUN = 6,
  JUL = 7,
  AUG = 8,
  SEP = 9,
  OCT = 10,
  NOV = 11,
  DEC = 12;

var FIRST = 1,
  SECOND = 2,
  THIRD = 3,
  FOURTH = 4,
  LAST = -1;

var HOLIDAYS = {
  "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day": [THIRD, MON, JAN],
  "Memorial Day": [LAST, MON, MAY],
  "Labor Day": [FIRST, MON, SEP],
  "Columbus Day": [SECOND, MON, OCT],
  "Thanksgiving Day": [LAST, THU, NOV]
};

var isFloatingHoliday = function(date, occurrence, weekDay, month) {

  if (date.getMonth() != month - 1) {
    return false;
  }

  if (date.getDay() != weekDay - 1) {
    return false;
  }

  var DAYS_IN_WEEK;

  if (occurrence == Math.ceil(date.getDate() / DAYS_IN_WEEK)) {
    return true;
  }

  var LAST = -1;
  if (occurrence != LAST) {
    return false;
  }

  var newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + DAYS_IN_WEEK);
  newDate.getMonth() + 1;

  return month != newDate.getMonth() + 1;
};

var getFloatingHoliday = function(date) {
  var results = Object.keys(HOLIDAYS).filter(function(val, index) {
    var occurrence = HOLIDAYS[val][0];
    var weekDay = HOLIDAYS[val][1];
    var month = HOLIDAYS[val][2];

    if (isFloatingHoliday(date, occurrence, weekDay, month)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });

  if (results.length) {
    return results[0];
  }

  return null;
}

   // ================== Test Cases ==================

console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('5/25/2020'), LAST, MON, MAY)); // true
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('5/25/2020'))); // Memorial Day

console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('11/26/2020'), LAST, THU, NOV)); // true
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('11/26/2020'))); // Thanksgiving Day

console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('1/1/2020'), LAST, THU, NOV)); // false
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('1/1/2020'))); // null
```

Here are several improvements made

- human-readable
- removal of if/else
- use of guard clauses to exit early
- mayfly variables
- reduction of magic numbers

Since we're humans and refer to months starting at 1 I've opted to create helpers to make the initialization of holidays easier to read.

months starting at 1

```js
var JAN = 1,
    FEB = 2,
    MAR = 3,
    APR = 4,
    MAY = 5,
    JUN = 6,
    JUL = 7,
    AUG = 8,
    SEP = 9,
    OCT = 10,
    NOV = 11,
    DEC = 12;
```

days of week starting at 1

```js
var SUN = 1,
    MON = 2,
    TUE = 3,
    WED = 4,
    THU = 5,
    FRI = 6,
    SAT = 7;
```

and occurrences

```js
var FIRST  = 1,
    SECOND = 2,
    THIRD  = 3,
    FOURTH = 4,
    LAST   = -1;
```

I'll break down the logic for each step of isFloatingHoliday

The first condition checks to see if the months match, if they don't
there's no point in continuing and return false

```js
if (date.getMonth() != month - 1) {
    return false;
}
```

The second condition checks to see if the day of week matches, if they don't
there's no point in continuing and return false

```js
if (date.getDay() != weekDay - 1) {
    return false;
}
```

The third condition attempts to find what occurrence the date provided falls in. We know at this point in the code we have the right month and day of week. All we need to figure out is what the occurrence is for the month.
To do that you just divide the date by 7 and round up.

1st - 7th  first occurrence
8th - 14th second occurrence
15th - 21st third occurrence
22nd - 28th fourth occurrence
29th +  fifth occurrence

If the given occurrence matches then there's nothing left to check, we got the correct month/date and occurrence, return true

```js
if (occurrence == Math.ceil(date.getDate() / 7)) {
    return true;
}
```

The fourth conditions figures out if we meant to check for the LAST occurrence which is signified by -1.  If not that means the
occurrences did not match so return false

```js
if (occurrence != -1) {
    return false;
}
```

The fifth part will calculate the date + 7 days to see if it falls within the same month.  If it does, that means that this date is not the last occurrence so return false.
However if the date 7 days later falls in a different month, we know that this was in fact the last occurrence and we return true

```js
var newDate = new Date(date);
newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
return month != newDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

I'll break down the logic for each step of getFloatingHoliday

The first step is to filter out any floating holidays that we have defined in HOLIDAYS.  Since the key is the holiday name and the value is an array describing the occurrence
we can use Object.keys to extract the keys into an array and filter through each one.

```js
Object.keys(HOLIDAYS)
.filter(function(val, index) {
    ...
});
```

Inside the filter we're extracting the values into a readable state and then using the existing isFloatingHoliday(...) function to see if the current date fits the description.  If not move on to the next.

```js
{
    var occurrence = HOLIDAYS[val][0];
    var weekDay = HOLIDAYS[val][1];
    var month = HOLIDAYS[val][2];

    if (isFloatingHoliday(date, occurrence, weekDay, month)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

After the filter executes it returns any keys that matched the HOLIDAY criteria and stores it in "results".  Given the nature of the holidays it's safe to assume any given date will only return 1 holiday at most.
So if there are any results we return the holiday.  If not then return null.

```js
if (results.length) {
    return results[0];
}

return null;
```

Here are some examples for you to try out

```js
console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('5/25/2020'), LAST, MON, MAY)); // true
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('5/25/2020'))); // Memorial Day

console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('11/26/2020'), LAST, THU, NOV)); // true
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('11/26/2020'))); // Thanksgiving Day

console.log(isFloatingHoliday(new Date('1/1/2020'), LAST, THU, NOV)); // false
console.log(getFloatingHoliday(new Date('1/1/2020'))); // null
```

I used this post as inspiration to expand on this. The examples shown are actual implementations I used to create a library for not only checking dates against holidays, but executing callbacks when matched.

https://github.com/eko3alpha/hollydates

Comment: The var `DAYS_IN_WEEK` remains undefined throughout the code.

Comment: The line `if (occurrence == Math.ceil(date.getDate() / DAYS_IN_WEEK)) return true;` will always give`false` because `DAYS_IN_WEEK` is undefined.

Comment: The line `newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + DAYS_IN_WEEK);` will always give `Nan` because `DAYS_IN_WEEK` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rows of if statements with if-else.

```
if (occurrence === 99) {
  var theDate = new Date(year,month+1,1+((first - (weekday >= new Date(year,month+1,1).getDay())) * 7) + (weekday - new Date(year,month+1,1).getDay())-7);
}else{
  var theDate = new Date(year,month,1+((occurrence - (weekday >= new Date(year,month,1).getDay())) * 7) + (weekday - new Date(year,month,1).getDay()));
}
```

This can definitely be changed to if-else.

```
if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 1 && month == 0) { holiday = "Martin Luther King, Jr. Dayear"; }
else if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 1 && month == 1) { holiday = "President's Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 2) { holiday = "Daylight Savings Time Begins"; }
else if (occurrence == 4 && weekday == 3 && month == 3) { holiday = "Administrative Assistants Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 4) { holiday = "Mother's Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 99 && weekday == 1 && month == 4) { holiday = "Memorial Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 0 && month == 5) { holiday = "Father's Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 3 && weekday == 0 && month == 6) { holiday = "Parents Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 1 && weekday == 1 && month == 8) { holiday = "Labor Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 0 && month == 8) { holiday = "Grandparents Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 99 && weekday == 0 && month == 8) { holiday = "Gold Star Mothers Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 2 && weekday == 1 && month == 9) { holiday = "Columbus Day"; }
else if (occurrence == 1 && weekday == 0 && month == 10) { holiday = "Daylight Savings Time Ends"; }
else if (occurrence == 4 && weekday == 4 && month == 10) { holiday = "Thanksgiving Day"; }
```

Also, use an if-else statement here.

```
if (holiday == ""){
 var displayDate = weekday[theDate.getDay()] + ', ' + mMonth[theDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + theDate.getDate() + ', ' + year;
} else{
  var displayDate = weekday[theDate.getDay()] + ', ' + mMonth[theDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + theDate.getDate() + ', ' + year + ' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + holiday;
}
```

This will make your code more efficient, if only slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with my GitHub repo, check it out here:

https://github.com/The-Best-Codes/bc-holiday.js/tree/main

## Usage

### Setting up the script

Include the JS library in your HTML documents like this:

```html
<script src="script/bc-holiday.js"></script>
```

Or use the URL to the file in the GitHub repo:

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/The-Best-Codes/bc-holiday.js/main/bc-holiday.js"></script>
```

#### Get the holidays for the current day

*Example: Returns the holidays for the current day*

```js
const holidaysToday = bcHoliday.getHolidaysOn(new Date());
console.log(holidaysToday);
/*Write the days holidays to the console as an array*/
```

#### Get the holidays for a time period between two dates

*Example: Get the holidays in November*

**Note that JavaScript is 0 based, so November, the 11th month, is 10 in JS**

```js
const holidaysThisMonth = bcHoliday.getHolidaysInRange(new Date(2023, 10, 1), new Date(2023, 10, 30));
console.log(holidaysThisMonth);
/*Write the days holidays to the console as an array*/
```

*Example: Show the holidays for November on an HTML page*

**Note that JavaScript is 0 based, so November, the 11th month, is 10 in JS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Holiday List</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    li {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .holiday-date {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Holiday List</h1>
  <ul id="holiday-list"></ul>

  <script>
    const holidaysData = bcHoliday.getHolidaysInRange(new Date(2023, 10, 1), new Date(2023, 10, 30));

    const holidayListElement = document.getElementById('holiday-list');

    for (const date in holidayData) {
      const holidayName = holidayData[date][0]; // Assuming only one holiday per date

      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      const dateElement = document.createElement('span');
      dateElement.classList.add('holiday-date');
      dateElement.textContent = formatDate(date);
      listItem.appendChild(dateElement);
      listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(': ' + holidayName));

      holidayListElement.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    function formatDate(dateString) {
      const [month, day] = dateString.split('-');
      return `${getMonthName(month)} ${parseInt(day)}${getDaySuffix(parseInt(day))}`;
    }

    function getMonthName(month) {
      const monthNames = [
        'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
      ];
      return monthNames[parseInt(month) - 1];
    }

    function getDaySuffix(day) {
      if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
        return 'th';
      }

      switch (day % 10) {
        case 1:
          return 'st';
        case 2:
          return 'nd';
        case 3:
          return 'rd';
        default:
          return 'th';
      }
    }
  </script>
<script src="script/path/to/bc-holiday.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Other functions and their usages

#### `formatDate(date)`

*Example: Return the current day in `MM-DD`  format*

```js
bcHoliday.formatDate(new Date());
```

```
'01-01'
```

#### `calculateEaster(year)`

*Example: Return the day on which Easter will occur for the supplied year*

```js
bcHoliday.calculateEaster(2030);
//Returns the date of Easter for the supplied year
```

```
Sun Apr 21 2030 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```