# Calculating Holidays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

As a learning exercise I took the question here: [calculate holidays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342753/calculate-holidays-in-javascript), and with a suggested approach, took it upon myself to develop a solution with ES6 array methods.

The previous stack post that is linked above suggested an object approach, but the answer did not include any code. I decided to use an array approach, and offer a complete coding example. The older post with 8K views, did not offer an array approach, and the OP already had an answer so I created a new question and self-answered.

I'm still learning, so I invite the pro's to improve upon this! I ran some performance tests and the if/then approach is faster, but this code works. Also as you can see I was not able to chain the .findIndex(), but that just results in another variable and another line of code. One note of caution, some ES6 array methods are not supported in older browsers.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: hi @rew check out the code review stackexchange, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I think this would be more relevant there, since you aren't experiencing a specific problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Hi @rew self answered questions are always welcome but the question should not be a duplicate and it should follow the default question template. This question doesn't have a [mcve]

Comment: The previous post did not have a complete coding answer, just a suggested approach.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The code is original. And it was self-answered which is permissible. Just trying to help others out. The previous post already had an answer which was not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check_holiday4(ds) {
  const [m, d, y] = ds.split('/');
  const h = [ // keys are formatted as month,week,day
    ["0,1", "New Year's Day"],
    ["0,3,1", "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day"],
    ["0,20", (function() {
      if (((y - 1937) % 4) == 0) return 'Inauguration Day'
    })()],
    ["1,14", "Valentine's Day"],
    ["1,3,1", "President's Day"],
    ["2,2,0", "Daylight Savings Time Begins"],
    ["3,3,3", "Administrative Professionals Day"],
    ["4,2,0", "Mother's Day"],
    ["4,5,1", "Memorial Day"],
    ["5,14", "Flag Day"],
    ["5,3,0", "Father's Day"],
    ["5,3,6", "Armed Forces Day"],
    ["6,4", "Independence Day"],
    ["6,4,0", "Parents Day"],
    ["8,1,1", "Labor Day"],
    ["9,2,1", "Columbus Day"],
    ["9,31", "Halloween"],
    ["10,11", "Veterans Day"],
    ["10,1,0", "Daylight Savings Time Ends"],
    ["10,1,2", "Election Day"],
    ["10,4,4", "Thanksgiving Day"],
    ["11,25", "Christmas Day"]
  ];
  const f = (a, n, d) => (d + 6 - new Date(...a, 7).getDay()) % 7 + n * 7 - 6;
  const dim = (y, m) => new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();
  const hc = (y, m) => h.filter(v => v[0].startsWith(m)).map((val, i) => {
    const [vm, vn, vdw] = val[0].split(',');
    let cd = f([y, vm], vn, +vdw);
    cd = (cd > dim(y, vm)) ? cd - 7 : (val[0].split(',').length === 2) ? vn : cd;
    val[0] = (+vm + 1) + "/" + cd + "/" + y;
    return [val[0], val[1]];
  });
  const ha = hc(y, m - 1);
  return ha[ha.findIndex(sa => sa[0] === ds)][1];
}

console.log(check_holiday4(new Date("10/31/2019").toLocaleDateString()));
// "Halloween"

console.log(check_holiday4(new Date("5/31/2021").toLocaleDateString()));
// "Memorial Day"
```

Comment: This is nice. Thank you. I have developed an alternative shorter approach which I will share soon.

Comment: The Election Day info is incorrect.