# Check if date is holiday in country

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Angular 12 and I would like to check if today is a working day or it's free day for workers. And it's not only about weekend but also about public holidays. I tried use date-holidays package but when I try import it like below

`import Holidays from 'date-holidays';`

and then use it:

`const hd = new Holidays('CZ');`

i receive a lot of errors like:

`./node_modules/astronomia/src/angle.js:1:0-122 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/slicedToArray' in '/Users/user/project/node_modules/astronomia/src'`

Where can be a problem? Maybe you can recommend me another package for this feature? I don't want to use moment.js.

Comment: Maybe this can help you?
[calculate holidays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342753/calculate-holidays-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to set holidays by myself because this feature have to work for a lot of countries, so I would like to use some package for it.

Answer (score 0):

Import `Holidays` in your Module:

```
    import { HolidayModule } from 'projects/angular-holiday-planner';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        ...
        HolidayModule
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: angular-holiday-planner is not what I'm looking for... I need package which show me non working days from all countries. Like date-holidays, but this package for some reasons doesn't work in my project.

Comment: The error you're getting is that you didn't import the package you're using in the module.